# Xcode 6.2 and watch device in simulator

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 6.2 and just testing the initial build of a watch app with no buttons, labels, text fields, just insuring that a blank app runs after adding the WatchApp as the target and selecting the watch in simulator hardware   I get the following error.

Asset Catalog set AppIcon has an unassinged image and
Ambiguous Content The app icon set "ApplIcon has unassigned image.

The simulator pops up with both the IPhone 6 and Watch images but I get these two errors

Comment: whats your question ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, please see **[Xcode 6.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)**

i.e.

> When creating a new Apple Watch app target, the newly created asset
>   catalog includes an "Unassigned" slot in the catalog's app icon.
>   Select the "Unassigned" slot and delete it using the Delete key.
>   (19978639)

The same is - at this moment- in Xcode 6.3.